# how to run many ajax separately? not step by step

Tags: javascript, jquery

how to run many ajax separately? not step by step.
please see my codes bellow.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    /* 
        there are 4 steps need to check with ajax,
        when all steps is checked , I will finally run final_fn
        I hate using $.ajax(...,function(){...}) to run ajax step after step.
        any other way to let script become more simple and easy to understand?
    */

    function final_fn(){
        //..
    }

    // my original way to check 4 steps
    $.ajax({
        url:'a.php',
        type:'POST',
        data:{},
        success:function(rs){
            // then run ajax b.php
                // then run ajax c.php
                    // then run ajax d.php
                        // then run final_fn
        }
    }); 

    // now i want to do it like bellow.
    $.ajax({
        url:'a.php',
        type:'POST',
        data:{},
        success:function(){}
    }); 

    $.ajax({
        url:'b.php',
        type:'POST',
        data:{},
        success:function(){}
    }); 
    // c.php
    // d.php
    // then final_fn()

    // how to do that? final_fn must run ater all steps complte

</script>
```

Comment: By "separately" do you mean "at the same time"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just have a counter, and each ajax increments it, then checks if it's 4 yet:

```
$.ajax({
    url:'a.php',
    type:'POST',
    data:{},
    success:function(){
        count++;
        if(count == 4) final_fn()
    }
}); 
$.ajax({
    url:'b.php',
    type:'POST',
    data:{},
    success:function(){
        count++;
        if(count == 4) final_fn()
    }
}); 
//etc.
```

Better yet would be to put it into a function, if that's the only thing you do on success

```
function doIt(url) {
    $.ajax({
        url:url,
        type:'POST',
        data:{},
        success:function(){
            count++;
            if(count == 4) final_fn()
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: He wants them to execute at the same time, *then* call final_fn.

Comment: That'll probably work fine. If this becomes frequent for you, it might be worth it to look at the principle of "promise" objects in JQuery. They're very useful for doing a bunch of things, and then a "next" function when those are done.

Comment: @mingfish_004 I do recommend paying attention to what Katana has said - I'm not a big user of JQuery, and I haven't yet had a reason to try out Promises.

Comment: thank you, and can you supply some toturials online ? @katana314 && jeff

Comment: @mingfish_004 A google search result that seemed to cover the topic well: http://www.htmlgoodies.com/beyond/javascript/making-promises-with-jquery-deferred.html (It's a bit much to describe in a comment)